# Is there a Java/Maven equivalent of package.jsons "bin"?

Tags: java, bash, shell, continuous-integration, devops

I'm in Java team where multiple repos need to access a shared set of CI/CD-related bash script files. In a Node team, I would publish a private NPM package exposing these scripts through the [`bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) entry of `package.json`, which other projects could then use after doing `npm install`.

I'm not sure if there's a good idea to introduce NPM to this project, so I need help to understand what the best approach would be in a more Java-oriented context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scripts are needed only by CI/CD they should be managed there, especially if you share them between the builds. You could replicate what you have with `package.json` by having JAR with `bin` scripts and unzipping it as part of the build but it's a brittle solution.

Modern CI/CD solutions use Docker containers to spin up a build environment (e.g. CircleCI, CloudBees). You can add `bin` scripts to the Docker image used to spin up a build environment node.

If this is not possible you still should be able to define build steps or pipelines. Define a common build step which installs these scripts.